# Can an algebra over an operad be described by generators and relations?

Tags: operads

Experts in operads, please be gentle to a beginner.

Suppose I have a collection of generators $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and some relations like
$$ x_1x_2 -x_5x_6x_7=0\qquad x_4x_8+2x_{11}x_{12}=3x_5x_6$$

Then, I can create an ordinary algebra with these generators and relations. For this I would take the free algebra on the symbols $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and quotient it over the two sided ideal generated by the relations above.

My question is can we do something similar for algebras over operads. Suppose I have a (non-symmetric) operad $\mathcal O=\{\mathcal O(n)\}$.

Now take a collection of symbols $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and some relations like

$$ \theta_2(x_1,x_2)+\theta_3(x_5,x_4,x_7)=0\qquad \theta_4(x_{10},
x_1,x_2,x_5)=0$$

where $\theta_n\in \mathcal O(n)$. I want to create an algebra $\mathcal A$
over the operad $\mathcal O$ with these generators and relations, satisfying an appropriate universal property. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, sure. You can take the free $\mathcal{O}$-algebra on your set of generators, and mod out by the $\mathcal{O}$-ideal generated by your relations. Then you get an algebra  $A$ presented by generators and relations. Thanks to the universal properties of free algebra and quotients by ideals, a morphism $A \to B$ is uniquely determined by the image of the generators, and it exists when these images satisfy the relations defining $A$. It works exactly as you would expect.

Comment: Hi, that's wonderful to know. Like I said, I am totally a beginner with operads. Could you give me a reference where I could find this construction?

Comment: I would say that one of the standard reference nowadays for learning about operads is the book "Algebraic Operads" by Loday and Vallette. In particular I would recommend Section 5.2, where free algebras and ideals are defined. They mostly work in symmetric operads rather than non-symmetric operads, but this is not much more complicated. They have a section about non-symmetric operads, but it's less detailed.

Comment: There is also Fresse's book, "Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck–Teichmüller groups", especially Part I(a). The book is long and deals with many of other things, but the beginning has a lot of background on the general theory of operads. @Operadbeginner